# Issue in sorting arraylist

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, arraylist

I am working on ArrayList for first time so expect some help in understanding it.

I am taking some user input and storing in ArrayList.

The input consist of single and double digit number.

If the single digit number is 1(at any index), the Arraylist is sorted properly.

If the single digit number is anything other than 1 the single digit number is not in sorted order(all other numbers are sorted).

Kindly ignore the first line of input as it's purpose is something else and the logic for the same is yet to be written.

The second line of input is the numbers to be stored in arraylist and sorted.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FindTheNo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String line;

    String s = br.readLine();
    String[] numbers = s.split(" ");

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

        String arr = line;
        String[] nos = arr.split(" ");

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < nos.length; i++) 
            al.add(nos[i]);

        Collections.sort(al);

        for(String s1: al)
        System.out.print(s1 +" ");

        System.out.println();
    //  System.out.println(al.get(6));
    }

}

}
```

input: 
1 5 9
10 58 63 47 25 63 9

Observed Output:
10 25 47 58 63 63 9

Expected Output:
9 10 25 47 58 63 63

Kindly advise where I am going wrong

Comment: `Collections.sort` method sorts the collection ascending to the natural order. Details in the javadoc of the [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) method. For strings the natural order is the `Observed Output` from the description. To get the `Expected Output` convert the strings to Integers using `Integer.valueOf(hereComesTheStringToConvert)` method

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're sorting `String`s and not `Integer`s. As `String` `"10"` is "smaller than" `"2"`. You need to change this:

```
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < nos.length; i++) 
        al.add(nos[i]);
```

into:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < nos.length; i++) 
        al.add(Integer.valueOf(nos[i]));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Please advise how is "10" smaller than "2".
Also while entering "1" it was the first element in the arraylist how did it work for "1" but not "2".

Comment: @Geek it's because you're looking at the first character. In the alphabet "1" is before "2". Same as "abc" would be "smaller than" "b".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort Strings instead of integers, So if we have '9' and '10' as Strings, it will be sorted as 10 followed by 9. Whereas if we sort it as Integers we will receive output as 9 followed by 10